# The number I'm trying to print out keeps getting add up in the next line

Tags: java, file, input, output

I want to read a few lines from a text document file and write the number of vowels from each line in another text document.

*"vlez.txt"* is the input file, and *"destinacija.txt*" is the output.

*Input -> Output example:*

> Hello
>   World
>   Goodbye

In the output file the result would be:

> 2   (2 vowels from Hello)
>   3   (1 vowel from World + previous)
>   7   (You get the point..)

My code :

```
package prvaZad;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class prvaZadaca {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("vlez.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("destinacija.txt"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        int number = 0;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');

            String lc = sb.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i=0; i<lc.length(); i++) {
                char ch = lc.charAt(i);

                if ("aeiouy".indexOf(ch) > -1) {
                    number++;
                }
            }
            out.print(number);
            out.print('\n');
            number = 0;
        }       

        if (in != null) 
            in.close();

        if (out != null)
            out.close();

        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code as text please, not images :)   
Also can you show a example of input->output?

Comment: Great. Can you show us the output you're currently getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep appending lines to the `StringBuilder`, in other words, it will restart counting from 0.

You can fix that by "clearing" the `StringBuilder` before the next iteration :

```
out.print(number);
out.print("\n")
number = 0;
sb = new StringBuilder(); // a new empty StringBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication11;

import java.util.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Sem-6-INGENIERIAINDU
 */
public class JavaApplication11 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "Hello World Goodbye";
        String[] container = word.split(" ");
        for (String container1 : container) {
            System.err.println("The word:" + container1 + " has " + (container1.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "")).length());
        }
    }

}
```

> run: The word:Hello has 2 The word:World has 1 The word:Goodbye has 3
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)